# "Mac-like" Linux distribution

Tags: linux-distribution

I have an ancient Mac that I'm looking at wiping when Lion support goes the way of the dinosaur. I still like the idea of keeping it as Mac-like as possible.

Are there any Linux distros that mimic to a very large degree OS X functionality? Interface bears more importance than under the hood development.

Comment: Since its a mac, what processor? If its a PPC model, your needs are going to be VERY different. You can also, reasonably simply hack together a mac-like theme off a basic cli only install.

Comment: I think that the real question is "which DE/WM is similar to OS X's".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: Clementine OS is now long dead. Please disregard this answer, and use eOS or something instead.**

---

[Clementine OS](http://clementineos.hj.cx/) aims to be as similar as possible to Mac OSX --  it boasts many of the same features, such as expose, and is visually almost the same. It comes from a now discontinued (sold) project called Pear Linux and has an interface virtually identical to that of Apple. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Clementine OS UI]

If you just want an Apple-like interface, I think I will go so far as to say that Clementine OS is perfect -- Oops! I just did --, although you may not like the Mavericks-style.

Under the hood, it is based on Ubuntu, so it is nice and stable and has a lot of available packages.

Comment: Clementine OS is no longer available. The German website heise.de posted this headline today: [heise.de](https://translate.google.at/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heise.de%2Fnewsticker%2Fmeldung%2FEndgueltiges-Aus-fuer-Pear-OS-2106897.html)

Comment: You can still use the themes and programs on Ubuntu, though. I expect.

Comment: Screen-shoots present Pear OS Linux which is also unavailable nowadays.

Comment: hmmmm, looks more like a parody (imho)

Comment: It seems that Clementine Linux is no longer active and the download link is broken (I was unable to find an updated link)

Answer (score 11):

[Elementary Luna OS](http://elementaryos.org/) aims to be as "Mac-like" as possible. It's built for usability and to visually look like Mac OS X.

[image: Elementary Luna OS UI]

<sup>Click to view in higher resolution</sup>

[Etoile](http://etoileos.com/etoile/) is a Linux distro aimed at using the GNUStep project to do system tasks, thus allowing a vaguely similar programming environment to Cocoa. While more similar to NextStep in terms of visual style, it will have some familiarity from a programming perspective.

Comment: I don't understand why people says that `elementary is looking like mac`. What is common in between mac and elementary? Is a dock all about being like Mac OS X?

Answer (score 8):

When I first got my MacBook Pro at the end of last year, I thought its UI was very similar to Unity (the default desktop environment in Ubuntu). Now, Unity is not 100% like Mac, but I think it's very close in many ways, especially when compared with most other distros. The top menu bar, the dock, the Settings app, etc. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Unity screenshot]

(I took the screenshot on my Retina display MacBook Pro, and unfortunately, Unity currently doesn't support HiDPI displays yet, so things look a little out of proportion. But I'm hoping that come [14.04 LTS release time, this will have ironed itself out](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/ubuntu-14-04-high-resolution-retina-screen).)

Here's another screenshot, showing the top menu:

[image: Showing the top menu]

The top menu style is quite reminiscent of the Mac UI, but with two differences:

1. There is no Apple menu.
2. The Alt-Tab task switcher is still window-centric (though windows are grouped by their owning application), not application-centric. This probably won't make a huge difference to you unless you're wedded to the "every application is basically MDI" aspect of the Mac UI.

---

**Update:** My boss tells me that Ubuntu 14.04 now does support HiDPI displays! Here's a screenshot of Unity (with Firefox 29 beta, that also supports HiDPI) running on his MacBook Pro 15 with Retina:

[image: Yay, Ubuntu 14.04 has HiDPI support!]

(I'll get around to updating the other screenshots soon.)